# "to go on picnic" vs "going on picnic"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

In this sentence:

> A friend of mine likes ________ on picnic at weekends.

Is it "to go" or "going"?

I reckon *to* + *verb* is usually used for a habit or preference.

Comment: Either is fine. (It should be *picnics*, plural. And if you're using US English, it should be *on* weekends.)

Comment: We don't usually use the form ***go on picnic*** - it's nearly always [***go picnicking***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+on+picnic%2Cgo+picnicking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20on%20picnic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20picnicking%3B%2Cc0) (except for a few people who aren't sure how to spell the "continuous verb" form! :) Or *go on **a** picnic*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm pretty sure I'd "go for a picnic" (in the UK, as you are).

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation, we would mostly use "A friend likes going on picnics on the weekends." "to go on picnics" would also be acceptable. I have heard people use picnicking, but it feels more outdated and not as commonly used. Like a documentary from the 1950's "The family enjoys picnicking in the park on weekends."

Answer (score 0):

First off, you go "on a picnic", not "on picnic".

Second, you use the prepisition "on" in front of "the weekend" in AmE, whereas you use "at" in BrE. In case of the plural weekends, you usually say weekends; the use of "the" before weekends is optional and less common.

Third, you  can use the infinitive "to go" or the -ing form "going" after the verb like. The use of the to-infinitive is more common in AmE.

So you can say:

A friend of mine likes to go/going on a picnic on the weekend.

You can also say "every weekend" instead of "on the weekend", but it's less common.